# In which situations it's needed to use volatile keyword with Atomic field?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, race-condition, volatile

In which situations it's needed to use volatile keyword with Atomic field? Or if the field is Atomic*** keyword volatile is redundant?

Thank you

Comment: It could be useful if you need to modify the reference, but that would be unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is nicely mentioned in `Java Concurrency In Practice` book:

- Volatile provides **Memory visibility** guarantee
- Atomic variables provide both **Memory visibility** and **Atomicity**

So there is ***no need*** to use volatile keyword with AtomicXXX variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no reason to make an Atomic field `volatile`. Atomic fields should be final, otherwise there is really no point in using them. If you declare an atomic integer like.

```
AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(420);
```

it can be accessed atomically through its methods such as `incrementAndGet`, but it is still possible to bypass them by assigning the field directly i.e. assigning a new value like this `integer = new AtomicInteger(10)` instead of `integer.set(10)` which defeats the entire purpose of using an `AtomicInteger` in the first place. Hence, it should be declared as final

```
final AtomicInteger integer = new AtomicInteger(420);
```

This ensures that it can only be changed using its atomic methods, and not by reassigning the variable. When a variable is `final`, declaring it also as `volatile` is pointless — Java won't even let you do it. So no, there is no practical scenario in which you will use the two together.

Answer (score 0):

None whatsoever.

> Or if the field is Atomic*** keyword volatile is redundant?

Either redundant or both not the right tool, depending on the situation.